# BoxLayout draw all widget in the corner

Tags: android, python, kivy, boxlayout

I'm trying to draw different widget in a box layout.
But if I try to draw some class, which extend widget, implemented by myself, the BoxLayout draw everything in the low left corner.
Trying to change size_hint and the size of the root didn't give any result.

```
BoxLayout:  
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Button:
        text: 'a'
    Label:
        text: 'b'
    Button:         
        text: 'c'
    TextInput:
        text: 'd'
```

Works

```
BoxLayout:  
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Widget:
        Button:
            text: 'a'
    Widget:
        Label:
            text: 'b'
```

gives problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget:
    Button:
```

That's putting a `Button` inside a `Widget` - not extending anything. However, `Widget` has no layout functionality and does not place its children anywhere - so they show up at `(0, 0)`.

Here's an example of extending a class in kv:

```
<MyButton@Button>:
    text: 'a'

BoxLayout:
    MyButton
```